# How to play restricted playback youtube videos on android using ionic framework

Tags: android, video, youtube, ionic-framework

I have the following code **to show youtube videos** under **ion-content** tag

```
<div class="video-container">
      <iframe src="{{videoUrl}}" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
</div>


.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Its working fine in browser but when I run it on android device it simply says:

```
'restricted to play on certain websites watch it on youtube'
```

and its not allowing me to click on watch it on youtube link.

I am using trusted url using **$sce.trustedResource** .

I searched in google little bit and found that we need to add referrer but how to add referrer in ionic framework.

Comment: Would you mind showing the exact URL of the video?

Comment: I tried your code on my android phone with another YouTube video and its working perfectly

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please try this url :https://www.youtube.com/embed/CevxZvSJLk8

Comment: Which browser do you use? Have you tried it in another browser or a different android phone?

Comment: I use chrome on desktop its working fine in chrome.  Are u able to play vevo videos on android using the above code? I have tested in 2 android devices its not working

Comment: hi @user1188867, did you find any solution to playing vevo youtube videos in ionic framework. please help me . all videos are playing in browser(using ionic serve) but testing in android phone. some videos are not playing. please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I have done a thorough research and I found out that there is no direct solution to this as the video is been protected by the owners against sites that doesn't provide their referral data by default, which the android doesn't have. But I created a page with the video embedded in it and uploaded it to my server and it played in android phone. So you can check it out [here](http://tutorials.stephensangkn.org/video). So if you upload it to your server it will surely play on an android phone. But if you don't want to upload it to a server, then the only solution here is to download the video from this [YouTube link](http://en.savefrom.net/#url=http://youtube.com/watch?v=CevxZvSJLk8&utm_source=youtube.com&utm_medium=short_domains&utm_campaign=ssyoutube.com) and then upload it back to your YouTube channel where there is no more restiction then you embed the new uploaded video instead of the restricted one.

Comment: I cannot upload the videos to my server. I have seen few links showing that its possible in ios and thought that it can be done in android as well. Anyway thanks for the effort you have put in.

Comment: You welcome. I don't actually mean you upload it to your server. What I meant is if you intend uploading the page to your server after building your web page then there won't be any problem in playing the video on android after its been uploaded to the server